# JavaScript for popping out categories list is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I need help with a JS function in HTML. I made a side nav with buttons and I used JS for popping out the categories list. They are supposed to hide when I click outside of them but they stack on top of each other. Could you tell me where is my mistake? I don't have any ideas left.

Maybe the problem is that I use separate functions for every button. But when I tried with one for all it didn't work either.

[image: screenshot of stacked lists]

```js
// JavaScript Document



/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function funcmoda() {
  document.getElementById("moda").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn ')) {
    var moda = document.getElementById("moda");
    if (moda.classList.contains('show')) {
      moda.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}


/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function funcfurn() {
  document.getElementById("obzavejdane").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn ')) {
    var obzavejdane = document.getElementById("obzavejdane");
    if (obzavejdane.classList.contains('show')) {
      obzavejdane.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}

/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function funcfabric() {
  document.getElementById("tekstil").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn ')) {
    var tekstil = document.getElementById("tekstil");
    if (tekstil.classList.contains('show')) {
      tekstil.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* Desktop Layout: 769px to a max of 1232px.  Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout and Tablet Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  .gridContainer {
    width: 88.5%;
    max-width: 1232px;
    padding-left: 0.75%;
    padding-right: 0.75%;
    margin: auto;
    clear: none;
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  #div1 {}
  .navbar {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
  .navbar a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .column {
    float: left;
  }
  /* Style links inside the columns */
  .column a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  /* Add a background color on hover */
  .column a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
  /* Clear floats after the columns */
  .row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
  .dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .navbar a:hover,
  .dropdown:hover .dropbtn,
  .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #16AA9E;
  }
  .dropbtn {
    width: 200px;
  }
  .column #subcolumn {}
  .dropdown-content {
    margin-left: 200px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .dropdown-content a {
    text-wrap: suppress;
    float: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 14px 16px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
  }
  h3 {
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .show {
    display: block;
  }
  .zeroMargin_desktop {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .hide_desktop {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <link href="boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="sidenavtry.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="sidenav.js" rel="scriptsheet" type="text/javascript">
  <!-- 
To learn more about the conditional comments around the html tags at the top of the file:
paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Do the following if you're using your customized build of modernizr (http://www.modernizr.com/):
* insert the link to your js here
* remove the link below to the html5shiv
* add the "no-js" class to the html tags at the top
* you can also remove the link to respond.min.js if you included the MQ Polyfill in your modernizr build 
-->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
  <script src="respond.min.js"></script>
  <script src="sidenav.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="gridContainer clearfix">
    <div id="div1" class="fluid">






      <div class="navbar">

        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn" id="btnModa" onclick="funcmoda()">Мода 
      
    </button>
          <div class="dropdown-content" id="moda">


            <div class="row">
              <div class="column">
                <h2>За нея</h2>

                <div class="column" id="subcolumn">
                  <h3>Дрехи</h3>
                  <a href="#">Тениски</a>
                  <a href="#">Блузи</a>
                  <a href="#">Панталони и дънънки</a>
                  <a href="#">Поли и рокли</a>
                  <a href="#">Якета и палта</a>
                  <a href="#">Спортни екипи</a>
                  <a href="#">Бельо</a>
                </div>

                <div class="column" id="subcolumn">
                  <h3>Обувки</h3>
                  <a href="#">Маратонки и кецеве</a>
                  <a href="#">Ежедневни обувки</a>
                  <a href="#">Обувки на ток</a>
                  <a href="#">Обувки на платформа</a>
                  <a href="#">Чехли и сандали</a>
                  <a href="#">Боти</a>
                  <a href="#">Ботуши</a>

                  <h3>Аксесоари</h3>
                  <a href="#">Колани</a>
                  <a href="#">Слъчеви очила</a>
                  <a href="#">Бижута и часовници</a>
                  <a href="#">Фиби, шноли и ластици</a>
                  <a href="#">Портфейли</a>

                </div>

                <div class="column" id="subcolumn">
                  <h3>Чанти и раници</h3>
                  <a href="#">Чанти за през рамо</a>
                  <a href="#">Пазарски чанти</a>
                  <a href="#">Клъч</a>
                  <a href="#">Пощальонска</a>
                  <a href="#">Раници</a>
                  <a href="#">Тип сак</a>
                  <a href="#">Тип кош</a>
                  <a href="#">Докторска</a>
                  <a href="#">Сетове чанти</a>


                </div>




              </div>
              <div class="column">
                <h2>За него</h2>
                <div class="column" id="subcolumn">
                  <h3>Дрехи</h3>
                  <a href="#">Тениски</a>
                  <a href="#">Блузи</a>
                  <a href="#">Панталони и дънки</a>
                  <a href="#">Якета и палта</a>
                  <a href="#">Спортни екипи</a>
                  <a href="#">Бельо</a>

                  <h3>Обувки</h3>
                  <a href="#">Маратонки и кецеве</a>
                  <a href="#">Ежедневни обувки</a>
                  <a href="#">Чехли и сандали</a>
                  <a href="#">Боти</a>
                  <a href="#">Ботуши</a>
                </div>
                <div class="column" id="subcolumn">
                  <h3>Чанти и раници</h3>
                  <a href="#">Чанти</a>
                  <a href="#">Раници</a>


                  <h3>Аксесоари</h3>
                  <a href="#">Колани</a>
                  <a href="#">Слъчеви очила</a>
                  <a href="#">Бижута и часовници</a>
                  <a href="#">Вратовръзки и папионки</a>
                  <a href="#">Портфейли</a>
                </div>


              </div>
              <div class="column">
                <h2>За детето</h2>
                <div class="column" id="subcolumn">
                  <h3>Бебешки дрехи</h3>
                  <a href="#">Бодита</a>
                  <a href="#">Блузи</a>
                  <a href="#">Панталони</a>
                  <a href="#">Спортни екипи</a>
                  <a href="#">Поли и рокли</a>
                  <a href="#">Лигавници</a>
                  <a href="#">Чорапи</a>
                </div>
                <div class="column" id="subcolumn">



                  <h3>Дрехи за момичета</h3>
                  <a href="#">Тениски</a>
                  <a href="#">Блузи</a>
                  <a href="#">Панталони и дънки</a>
                  <a href="#">Рокли и поли</a>
                  <a href="#">Спортни екипи</a>
                  <a href="#">Якета и палта</a>
                  <a href="#">Бельо</a>

                </div>
                <div class="column" id="subcolumn">

                  <h3>Дрехи за момчета</h3>
                  <a href="#">Тениски</a>
                  <a href="#">Блузи</a>
                  <a href="#">Панталони и дънки</a>
                  <a href="#">Спортни екипи</a>
                  <a href="#">Якета и палта</a>
                  <a href="#">Бельо</a>

                  <h3>Обувки</h3>
                  <a href="#">Ританки</a>
                  <a href="#">Обувки за момичета</a>
                  <a href="#">Обувки за момчета</a>
                </div>


              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn" id="btnFurn" onclick="funcfurn()">Обзавеждане 
      
    </button>
          <div class="dropdown-content" id="obzavejdane">


            <div class="row">
              <div class="column">

                <div class="column" id="subcolumn">
                  <h3>Спалня</h3>
                  <a href="#">Легла</a>
                  <a href="#">Гардероби</a>
                  <a href="#">Шкафове</a>
                  <a href="#">Модулни системи</a>

                </div>
                <div class="column" id="subcolumn">
                  <h3>Хол</h3>
                  <a href="#">Мека мебел</a>
                  <a href="#">Холни маси</a>
                  <a href="#">Етажерки</a>
                  <a href="#">Модулни системи</a>


                </div>
                <div class="column" id="subcolumn">
                  <h3>Трапезаря</h3>
                  <a href="#">Маси</a>
                  <a href="#">Столове</a>
                  <a href="#">Шкафове</a>
                  <a href="#">Модулни системи</a>


                </div>
                <div class="column" id="subcolumn">
                  <h3>Кухня</h3>
                  <a href="#">Горни шкафове</a>
                  <a href="#">Долни шкафове</a>
                  <a href="#">Помощни маси</a>
                  <a href="#">Мивки</a>
                  <a href="#">Плотове</a>
                  <a href="#">Модулни системи</a>
                </div>


                <div class="column" id="subcolumn">
                  <h3>Офис</h3>
                  <a href="#">Бюра</a>
                  <a href="#">Офис столове</a>
                  <a href="#">Етажеркки</a>
                  <a href="#">Шкафове</a>
                  <a href="#">Модулни системи</a>

                </div>
                <div class="column" id="subcolumn">

                  <h3>Детска стая</h3>
                  <a href="#">Легла</a>
                  <a href="#">Гардероби</a>
                  <a href="#">Шкафове</a>
                  <a href="#">Модулни системи</a>
                </div>
                <div class="column" id="subcolumn">
                  <h3>Антре</h3>
                  <a href="#">Шкафове</a>
                  <a href="#">.......</a>
                  <a href="#">.......</a>
                  <a href="#">.......</a>
                  <a href="#">.......</a>



                </div>


                <div class="column" id="subcolumn">
                  <h3>Декор</h3>
                  <a href="#">Стенни декорации</a>
                  <a href="#">Осветление</a>
                  <a href="#">.....</a>
                  <a href="#">.....</a>
                  <a href="#">.....</a>
                  <a href="#">.....</a>
                  <a href="#">.....</a>
                </div>


              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>



        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn" id="btnFabric" onclick="funcfabric()">Текстил</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content" id="tekstil">


            <div class="row">
              <div class="column">

                <div class="column" id="subcolumn">
                  <h3>Платове</h3>
                  <a href="#">Вид плат</a>
                  <a href="#">Вид плат</a>
                  <a href="#">Вид плат</a>
                  <a href="#">Вид плат</a>
                  <a href="#">Вид плат</a>
                  <a href="#">Вид плат</a>
                  <a href="#">Вид плат</a>
                  <a href="#">Вид плат</a>



                </div>
                <div class="column" id="subcolumn">
                  <h3>Домашен текстил</h3>
                  <a href="#">Долни чаршафи</a>
                  <a href="#">Горни чаршафи</a>
                  <a href="#">Калъвки за възглавници</a>
                  <a href="#">Завивки</a>
                  <a href="#">Одеала</a>
                  <a href="#">Килими</a>
                  <a href="#">Пердета</a>
                  <a href="#">Покривки</a>


                </div>
                <div class="column" id="subcolumn">
                  <h3>Други</h3>
                  <a href="#">......................</a>
                  <a href="#">......................</a>
                  <a href="#">......................</a>
                  <a href="#">......................</a>
                  <a href="#">......................</a>


                </div>
                <div class="column" id="subcolumn">
                  <h3>Още други</h3>
                  <a href="#">......................</a>
                  <a href="#">......................</a>
                  <a href="#">......................</a>
                  <a href="#">......................</a>
                  <a href="#">......................</a>
                  <a href="#">......................</a>
                </div>



              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>







      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only code that was being executed was the last `window.onclick` (
you were redefining `'window.onclick'`)

Solution:

```js
// JavaScript Document



/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function funcmoda() {
  document.getElementById("moda").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn ')) {
    var moda = document.getElementById("moda");
    if (moda.classList.contains('show')) {
      moda.classList.remove('show');
    }
    var obzavejdane = document.getElementById("obzavejdane");
    if (obzavejdane.classList.contains('show')) {
      obzavejdane.classList.remove('show');
    }
    var tekstil = document.getElementById("tekstil");
    if (tekstil.classList.contains('show')) {
      tekstil.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}

/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function funcfurn() {
  document.getElementById("obzavejdane").classList.toggle("show");
}

/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function funcfabric() {
  document.getElementById("tekstil").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

This is my first answer, so, forgive for the lack of professionalism, and my english =)

Comment: Alberto Guilherme, thank you very much.Your solution worked perfectly. Now the function does what it`s suppoused to do :)

Comment: Now there is another issue with the function. If I click btnModa and after that I click btnFabric the content for btnModa stays and the content for btnFabric comes on top. All the buttons are in the same class with diferent id. Should I make a diferent class for every btn to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

So I finally figured it out. In order for the drop categories to respond correctly I had to make separate buttons for each category ( I mean separate classes ) This combined with the answer given by Alberto Guilherme for the JS function fixed the problem.

```js
function funcmoda() {
  document.getElementById("moda").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.btnModa ')) {
    var moda = document.getElementById("moda");
    if (moda.classList.contains('show')) {
      moda.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
  if (!e.target.matches('.btnFurn ')) {
    var obzavejdane = document.getElementById("obzavejdane");
    if (obzavejdane.classList.contains('show')) {
      obzavejdane.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
  if (!e.target.matches('.btnFabric ')) {
    var tekstil = document.getElementById("tekstil");
    if (tekstil.classList.contains('show')) {
      tekstil.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}

/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function funcfurn() {
  document.getElementById("obzavejdane").classList.toggle("show");
}

/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function funcfabric() {
  document.getElementById("tekstil").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.navbar {
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown .btnModa {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.dropdown .btnFurn {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.dropdown .btnFabric {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .btnModa,
.dropModa:focus {
  background-color: #16AA9E;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .btnFurn,
.dropFurn:focus {
  background-color: #16AA9E;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .btnFabric,
.dropModa:focus {
  background-color: #16AA9E;
}

.btnModa {
  width: 200px;
}

.btnFurn {
  width: 200px;
}

.btnFabric {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btnModa" onclick="funcmoda()">Мода</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content" id="moda">
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btnFurn" onclick="funcfurn()">Обзавеждане</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content" id="obzavejdane"></div>
 <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btnFabric" onclick="funcfabric()">Текстил</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content" id="tekstil"> </div>
</div>
```